# Upgrade to cordova-android 11: Plugin cordova-plugin-video-editor will not work anymore

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I just updating my ionic project to Cordova Android 11 (because of android-targetSdkVersion which must be > 30 this fall).

Seems that good old plugin cordova-plugin-video-editor will not work anymore when building the project:

```
import net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.MediaTranscoder;
                                    ^
/Users/olivierschmid/AppDev/b2c-customer-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/videoeditor/CustomAndroidFormatStrategy.java:6: error: package net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.format does not exist
import net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.format.MediaFormatStrategy;
                                           ^
/Users/olivierschmid/AppDev/b2c-customer-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/videoeditor/CustomAndroidFormatStrategy.java:7: error: package net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.format does not exist
import net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.format.OutputFormatUnavailableException;
                                           ^
/Users/olivierschmid/AppDev/b2c-customer-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/videoeditor/CustomAndroidFormatStrategy.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class CustomAndroidFormatStrategy implements MediaFormatStrategy {
```

Does someone have a tipp what alternative I can try (for compressing videos)? There seem not to be many options?

Thanks! Oli

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried adding "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"?

Comment: Thanks - yes - "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" is installed. I now removed the plugin completely :-(

Comment: it seems that there are several plugins that are having problems with android 12 https://volt.build/docs/android_12/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).